# Trim spaces in header of an excel file in PHP

Tags: php

The user is uploading an excel file and if there are spaces in the header I  have to remove it and upload .Is it possible using PHP ?

My excel file is like this and there as spaces in the header.I need to remove it and then only transfer the file to server

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but we need a bit more context to be able to help you properly. Please include some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you using to perform operations on that excel file?

Comment: I know only the trim function but not sure I can use it for excel files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file without downloading it this way [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) :

```php
$file_content = file_get_contents($_FILES['input_file']['tmp_name']);
```

For your example, `echo $file_content;` will return something like this :

```
NAME ;AGE ;PLACE 
john  ;   22; Sydney
Riya  ;  33;Sydney
```

Then you can remove all spaces

```php
$file_content = str_replace(' ', '', $file_content);
```

You can now create a file, name it what ever you want and write `$file_content` in it.
Another thing you could do was to download it and then modify the file content.
Please make sure your files have the `.csv` extensions to your excel file.